# How to subclass another application control using DLL hook in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll-injection

I'm trying to make this example work, the idea is to change Notepad edit control color to red:

dll

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")

#pragma data_seg("SHARED")

HWND hWndNotepad = nullptr;

#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:SHARED,RWS")

HINSTANCE hInst;
HHOOK hGetMsgHook;
BOOL bSubclassed = FALSE;

#define WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE WM_USER + 10

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        hInst = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        char out[64] = { 0 };
        sprintf_s(out, 63, "DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, bSubclassed: %i", (int)bSubclassed);
        OutputDebugStringA(out);

        if (bSubclassed)
        {
            RemoveWindowSubclass(hWndNotepad, SubclassProc, 0);
            bSubclassed = FALSE;
            hWndNotepad = nullptr;
        }
    }
    break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL CALLBACK SetHook(BOOL bInstall)
{
    if (bInstall)
    {
        hWndNotepad = FindWindowA("Notepad", NULL);
        if (hWndNotepad)
        {
            char out[256] = { 0 };

            hGetMsgHook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)GetMsgProc, hInst, 0);
            if (hGetMsgHook)
            {
                DWORD dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndNotepad, NULL);
                PostThreadMessageA(dwThreadId, WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)hWndNotepad);

                sprintf_s(out, 255, "hWndNotepad: %08X - Thread Id : %08X", (UINT)hWndNotepad, dwThreadId);
            }
            else {
                sprintf_s(out, 255, "Error SetWindowsHookEx: %d", GetLastError());
            }

            OutputDebugStringA(out);
        }
        else
        {
            char out[] = "Notepad not found";
            OutputDebugStringA(out);

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (hGetMsgHook)
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hGetMsgHook);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSG* lpMsg;
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        lpMsg = (MSG*)lParam;
        if (lpMsg->message == WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE)
        {
            char out[128] = { 0 };
            sprintf_s(out, 127, "WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE - hWndNotepad : %08X", (UINT)hWndNotepad);
            OutputDebugStringA(out);

            bSubclassed = SetWindowSubclass((HWND)hWndNotepad, SubclassProc, 0, 0);

            if (!bSubclassed) {
                sprintf_s(out, 127, "Error SetWindowSubclass : %d", GetLastError());
                OutputDebugStringA(out);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hGetMsgHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    char out[32] = { 0 };
    sprintf_s(out, 31, "uMsg : %d", uMsg);
    OutputDebugStringA(out);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    {
        SetDCBrushColor((HDC)wParam, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
    }
    break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

main program:

```cpp
HINSTANCE hinstDLL = nullptr;
BOOL hookset = false;

typedef BOOL(*SetHookType)(BOOL);
SetHookType SetHook = nullptr;

DWORD WINAPI dllTest(LPVOID) {

    char out[128] = { 0 };

    sprintf_s(out, 127, "--- dllTest beg ---");
    OutputDebugStringA(out);

    hookset = !hookset;

    if(hinstDLL == nullptr) {
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
    #if _WIN64
        hinstDLL = LoadLibraryA("F:\\projects\\_dll_hook\\x64\\Release\\hook.dll");
    #else
        hinstDLL = LoadLibraryA("F:\\projects\\_dll_hook\\Release\\hook.dll");
    #endif
#endif
        sprintf_s(out, 127, "DLL loaded");
        OutputDebugStringA(out);
    }

    if (hinstDLL == nullptr) {
        sprintf_s(out, 127, "Error loading dll: #%d", GetLastError());
        OutputDebugStringA(out);
        return 0;
    }

    if (SetHook == nullptr) {
        SetHook = (SetHookType)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "SetHook");
        if (SetHook == nullptr) {
            sprintf_s(out, 127, "Error getting address of dll.SetHook: #%d", GetLastError());
            OutputDebugStringA(out);
            return 0;
        }
        SetHook(hookset);
    }

    if (!hookset) {
        FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
        hinstDLL = nullptr;
        SetHook = nullptr;
        sprintf_s(out, 127, "DLL freed");
        OutputDebugStringA(out);
    }

    Sleep(10000);  // <-- ONE POSSIBLE SOLUTION

    sprintf_s(out, 127, "--- dllTest end ---");
    OutputDebugStringA(out);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get after calling dllTest twice:

```
[13800] --- dllTest beg ---
[13800] DLL loaded
[13800] hWndNotepad: 002B0FAC - Thread Id : 00003B30
[13800] --- dllTest end ---
[13800] DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, bSubclassed: 0
[10356] WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE - hWndNotepad : 002B0FAC
[10356] DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, bSubclassed: 1
[13800] --- dllTest beg ---
[13800] DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, bSubclassed: 0
[13800] DLL freed
[13800] --- dllTest end ---
```

It looks like WM_NOTEPADMESSAGE is sent to the Notepad window but is not captured by GetMsgProc.
What might be wrong in this code and how to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `dllTest()` and `SetHook()` calls run in your own process, but the message hook will run in the thread that owns the Notepad window, which is in another process. That means your DLL will be loaded into the Notepad process, and your `callback` variable will be invalid in that context. Your logging approach can’t work across process boundaries, so you won’t see any logging from your message hook or subclass procedure. Consider using `OutputDebugString()` instead, and use [SysInternals DebugView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to see the messages.

Comment: Shouldn't "callback" be available to all DLL because it's in the shared segment? But above all, I don't see any changes to Notepad background, which means this code doesn't work, regardless of logging.

Comment: yes, the `callback` pointer itself will be in a shared segment, but the function it points at will only be valid in the context of your process, not the NotePad process. You can’t call functions over process boundaries. And without your logging, you don’t even know if your subclassing is working, unless you load Notepad into your debugger and step through your hook code in real-time

Comment: Other processes cannot access the function address in your process.

Comment: Thank you, I rewrote the code with the proper output functions and changed it in the OP.

Comment: use not `WH_GETMESSAGE` but `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `SendMessageW` to window  instead `PostThreadMessageA` (because this call synchronous) and remove hook just after this - it not need more. before `SetWindowSubclass` you need add reference to your dll, for it not unloaded until callback set. and deference dll after call  `RemoveWindowSubclass` (it must be not in dll detach ). call `RemoveWindowSubclass` from `WM_NCDESTROY` or by some your private message. and initial entry - `SubclassProc`, if you design unload, must be in asm, for call finally `FreeLibrary` with `jmp`

Comment: @RbMm Unfortunately, the complexity of this is way over my head, I won't be able to write such code or understand what it does. I'm pretty happy with the solution I have now that compiles and works in MSVS.

Answer (score 1):

First, The reason callback does not work is your DLL will be injected into the target process, and other processes cannot access the function address in the main program.

Then, I can reproduce your issue(the notepad background cannot be changed). The main program ends immediately after `SetHook`, and the system may automatically unregister your hook, and then the target process is unable to access the `SubclassProc` address. Try to Add any delay in the main program, like a message loop.